# Parallel processing using DataFrames in Julia

Tags: julia

I am referring to the example in the documentation for processing [Parallel loops](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/index.html#Parallel-Map-and-Loops-1) and trying to adapt it for my use case. In each independent iteration in my case, I  get a `DataFrame` as a result which I need to finally combine across all iterations using `vcat()`. This is a simplified version of my attempt so far:

```
using DataFrames, Distributed

function test()
    if length(workers()) < length(Sys.cpu_info())
        addprocs(length(Sys.cpu_info()); exeflags="--project=" * Base.active_project())
    end

    nheads = @distributed (vcat) for i = 1:20
        DataFrame(a=[Int(rand(Bool))])
    end
end
```

But on running `test()`, I get the error:

> ERROR: On worker 2: UndefVarError: DataFrame not defined

What do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: Another approach to load the processes with your environment is to launch julia in this way: julia --project="path_to_environment" -e "using Distributed;addprocs(length(Sys.cpu_info()); exeflags=\"--project=\" * Base.active_project());include(\"path_to_file_to_run.jl\");" to run the file with the code in the answer, without the line having addprocs()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `using DataFrames ...` statement on the first line only applies to the main "thread". So your worker threads didn't import the required libraries.

To fix this, you should add the keyword `@everywhere` on the first line. That would ask all the processes to import those libraries.

**Edit**

Just noticed that you did `addprocs` in the function. Then my suggestion wouldn't work. Here's a working version:

```
using Distributed

addprocs(length(Sys.cpu_info()))

@everywhere using DataFrames

function test()
    nheads = @distributed (vcat) for i = 1:20
        DataFrame(a=[Int(rand(Bool))])
    end
end

test()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but now I get the error: evaluation error: mod = Main, ex =  @everywhere using DataFrames, exception = type Nothing has no field framedata

Comment: Hm weird. This works for me. What version of Julia are you using?

Comment: It's Julia 1.1.0. Strangely, it works when @everywhere using DataFrames is run in the REPL, but not through the code above

Comment: On further looking into this, the code works as long as DataFrames is installed in the default Julia environment (v1.1 in my case). If you have DataFrames installed only on a project-specific environment which you use, then it does not work.